# Diameters of moons in solar system

Tags: planetary-science, solar-system, moons

I would like to programmatically find all moons in our solar system above a certain diameter.  I would like to use the api to jpl horizons if possible.  (For context I am then going on to find positions of all those moons at different times)

Comment: I think you will find plenty of information how to extract position information using the Horizons API by searching previous questions and answers here. That question would be closed as a duplicate, but really there will be several questions and their answers that will be helpful. **However**, the "all the moons in our solar system" aspect is a little tricky. Usually one already knows which body one is looking for. Now you need *all of them* and so need a systematic way to ask the API for each one separately. I think that that's the unique aspect of your question.

Comment: There is a way to get a list of the NAIF IDs for all of the bodies Horizons knows about.  I don't have a link handy, but look in the documentation for the Body ID field.

Comment: I assume you only want moons of planets, not moons of asteroids. Horizons classes planetary moons as major bodies. It's easy to find their ID numbers: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=%27%2A%27

Comment: This task is slightly messy because some satellite body data pages list the radius, some list the mean radius, (eg, https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=505 )  and some have no radius data.

Comment: Thanks all for comments.
That's a great help and points me at some useful resources :-)